# How to copy data with sshpass between two remote machines?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am new to bash and currently working on a script. I am working with two remote machines and accessing them via sshpass (I know its not good to hardcode passwords but I am supposed to do it this way). So if I want to copy stuff from my local machine to the remote one I am doing it like this:

```
    sshpass -p $PASS scp <file> <destination>
```

But now I want to copy data from one remote machine to the other.
Is this possible or do I have to buffer the data on my local machine?
If its possible how should the syntax should look like? I would somehow need sshpass for both arguments, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you ssh between two remote machines directly?

run this from your local machine. (machine1 and mechine2 are remote servers)

```
sshpass -p $PASS1 ssh user1@machine1 "sshpass -p $PASS2 scp file user2@machine2:/destination"
```

set keyless in ssh/scp between two remote servers and your local desktop to remote server. Then you needn't sshpass [SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

```
ssh user1@machine1 "scp file user2@machine2:/destination"
```

Comment: Like running the sshpass and scp on the remote machine? I tried that but sshpass is not installed on it. I am note sure if I am allowed to install it so I would appreciate another way.

Comment: The finished script shall automize a program routine and will run on different local machines. They don't use public and private keys here so that won't be an option. If there comes no other answere I will mark yours as the solution.

Comment: I would argue that the failure to use public key authentication is a design flaw in your system.